# jQuery UI SelectMenu Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

i'm trying to implement the jQuery UI SelectMenu but i become again and again the same error in the browser console.

Here is the HTML Code

```
<select name="files" id="files">
  <optgroup label="Scripts">
    <option value="jquery">jQuery.js</option>
    <option value="jqueryui">ui.jQuery.js</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Other files">
    <option value="somefile">Some unknown file</option>
    <option value="someotherfile">Some other file with a very long option text</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

and the Javascript / jQuery Code

```
$(function() {

$( "#files" ).selectmenu();

});
```

Its the same from the jQuery UI Website but in don't work by me.

This is the Error:

> jquery-3.0.0.js:9779 Uncaught TypeError: elem.getClientRects is not a function

I hope anyone have ideas.

Thank You

Comment: which jQueryUI version you are using?

Comment: I check a oder Version of jquery (2.4) and it works fine but i hope anyone find a way why i become the error on 3.0. I want to use 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are compatibility issues with `jquery` version `>= 3.0` with older `jquery-ui` or might be the latest one. I would suggest you to include `jquery-migrate-3.0.js` and see if this works good.

As per the **[`release doc`](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/)**:

> To assist with upgrading, we have a brand new **[`3.0 Upgrade Guide`](http:////jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/)**. And the **[`jQuery Migrate 3.0 plugin`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate#migrate-older-jquery-code-to-jquery-30)** will help you to identify compatibility issues in your code. Your feedback on the changes will help us greatly, so please try it out on your existing code and plugins.
>
> In addition, we’ve got the release for jQuery Migrate 3.0. We highly
>   recommend using this to address any issues with breaking changes in
>   jQuery 3.0. You can get those files here:
>
> **[`jquery-migrate-3.0.js`](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js)**
>
> **[`jquery-migrate-3.0.min.js`](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js)**

## [`Fiddle DEMO with jquery migrate 3.0 included`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/07nm0je0/1/)

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)